# whereclause with substring in clickhouse

Tags: sql, where-clause, clickhouse

I am trying to get all rows that contain a substring from a particular column in clickhouse

`SELECT Column1, count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 CONTAINS 'word1'`

All I need is results that include word1 in column1 and the number of occurrences of each in the entire table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count the frequency of each superstring of 'word1', you need a `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT Column1, count(*)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Column1 LIKE '%word1%'
GROUP BY Column1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(Column1) AS Column1Count FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%word1%'
```

I've checked on clickhouse this should work. The '%' sign will give you the contain feature - if you need to insert it using a variable just use concatenation.